# Why GADBannerView is undeclared?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, admob

I just wanted to add ads into my new app.

In my other apps, I added ads by manually copying the framework to the project. But this time, I decided to use the `Firebase/AdMob` cocoapod. So I added these lines:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
```

I added the core because I also want Firebase analytics.

Usually, after I add a pod, I would go to the project settings and link the newly added pod in the "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" section. But I can't find the framework when I press the + button. So I didn't do it.

Then I just set up Firebase in the App Delegate:

```
FIRApp.configure()
```

The app runs perfectly and I can see the "Firebase analytics enabled" message in the console.

After that, I added ad banners in the storyboard, just like [the guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/quick-start) has said.

Then I control-dragged the ad banner view to the controller and added an outlet:

```
@IBOutlet var ad: GADBannerView!
```

Now it says `GADBannerView` is undeclared. I realized that I forgot to import the module, so I added:

```
import GoogleMobileAds
```

just like the guide did. But *it still says the type is undeclared!* I cleaned and rebuilt, still no luck.

Then I thought that maybe the guide made a mistake, maybe I should import Firebase instead:

```
import Firebase
```

But `GADBannerView` is still undeclared.

Then the strangest thing happened: I command + clicked `GADBannerView` to see its definition. And then Xcode successfully jumped to the definition in `GADBannerView.h` and highlighted:

```
@interface GADBannerView : UIView
```

If `GADBannerView` is an undeclared type, how did I find the definition?

Side Note:

The compiler also can't find the method `GADMobileAds.configureWithApplicationID` which the guide told me to call.

Comment: Got the same problem after adding `pod 'Firebase/Crash'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several things you should check:

1. If you was using CocoaPods to install the SDK, make sure you are opening the .xcworkspace instead of .xcodeproj
2. Try to delete Derived Data (Window -> Project -> Delete...), Clean (Cmd+Shift+K) and Rebuild project.
3. You don't really have to import "Firebase" to make BannerAd works. You just want to import it in AppDelegate for other benefits of this platform.

Comment: I deleted the derived data and now whenever I build, I get a segfault...

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4:**

i had to import GoogleMobileAds in the view controller

```
import GoogleMobileAds
```

and in AppDelegate

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleMobileAds
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to import GoogleMobileAds to the view controller where your outlet is at.
cheers

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by adding `use_frameworks!` to the Podfile. It enables swift dynamic frameworks ([see blogpost).](https://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-0.36/)

As a reference I used [Podfile from the sample project:](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/admob/Podfile)

```
use_frameworks!
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'Firebase/AdMob'

target 'AdMobExample' do
end
target 'AdMobExampleSwift' do
end
target 'AdMobExampleTests' do
end
target 'AdMobExampleSwiftTests' do
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue on undeclared `GADAdLoader`.

Tried FlySoFast's answer, it didn't work for me unfortunately.

Needed to import Firebase to solve my issue.

I'm using Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK 7.29.0